# Change Feed Processor Issue

Tags: .net, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-changefeed

I am trying to test change feed processor in .net. I have tried to use the change feed processor from the beginning (as mentioned in documentation). When I start the change feed processor, it is running as expected, if I make a change in COSMOS db, it is triggering HandleChanges method. I wanted to test one scenario: I have stopped my change feed processor locally, made 2 changes to cosmos db and started the processor, this time the processor was only picking the latest change. Why is this? Am I missing something in the code?

This is my code:

```
    public class ChangeFeedListener 
    {
        private static CosmosClient _cosmosClient;
        private static Database _productDatabase;
        private static Container _productContainer;
        private static Container _productLeaseContainer;
        private IAuditMessenger _auditMessenger = null;

        public ChangeFeedListener(IAuditMessenger auditMessenger,TelemetryClient telemetryClient)
        {
            _auditMessenger = auditMessenger;
            _telemetryClient = telemetryClient;
        }
        public async Task StartListener(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            
            _cosmosClient = new CosmosClient(Config.CosmosConfig.ConnectionString);
            _productDatabase = _cosmosClient.GetDatabase(Config.CosmosConfig.CosmosDB);
            _productContainer = _productDatabase.GetContainer(Config.CosmosConfig.TriggerContainer);
            _productLeaseContainer = _productDatabase.GetContainer(Config.CosmosConfig.LeaseContainer);

            await StartChangeFeedProcessorAsync(_cosmosClient);
        }

        private async Task<ChangeFeedProcessor> StartChangeFeedProcessorAsync(
            CosmosClient cosmosClient)
        {
            

            Container.ChangeFeedMonitorErrorDelegate onErrorAsync = (string LeaseToken, Exception exception) =>
            {
                if (exception is ChangeFeedProcessorUserException userException)
                {
                    //handle
                }
                else
                {
                    //handle
                }

                return Task.CompletedTask;
            };

            

            Container leaseContainer = cosmosClient.GetContainer(_productDatabase.Id, _productLeaseContainer.Id);

            string processorName = "abc";
            string instanceName = "test";

            

            ChangeFeedProcessor changeFeedProcessor = cosmosClient.GetContainer(_productDatabase.Id, _productContainer.Id)
                .GetChangeFeedProcessorBuilder<ABCItem>(processorName, HandleChangesAsync)
                .WithErrorNotification(onErrorAsync)
                .WithInstanceName(instanceName) 
                .WithLeaseContainer(leaseContainer)
                .WithStartTime(DateTime.MinValue.ToUniversalTime())
                .Build();


            
            await changeFeedProcessor.StartAsync();

            
            
            return changeFeedProcessor;
        }

        private async Task HandleChangesAsync(
            IReadOnlyCollection<ABCItem> changes,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            //handler code
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Are the 2 changes you are doing on the same document?

Comment: No,  different documents in same container

Comment: If you have multiple lease documents and some of them have no Continuation (null) when you stop it, then that might generate the case you are describing, similar to the note in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/change-feed-processor#error-handling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was using service fabric explorer, even after I stopped local debugging, the listener continued to run in the background, hence it was processing them in the background. There was no data loss and it worked fine.
I realized this when the continuation token with TS seemed to changed even after I stopped the listener

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you did the change in the same document, if you make changes in the same document within the same time period, change feed will only send you the latest one not every change.

If you change multiple documents you will see changes for each document in turn in the order they were changed.

Here is a working example

```
[FunctionName("IntermediateDataChangeFeedListener")]
        public async Task Run([CosmosDBTrigger(
            databaseName: "productdata",
            collectionName: "intermediatedata",
            ConnectionStringSetting = "cosmosDBConnectionString",
            LeaseCollectionName = "lease")]IReadOnlyList<Document> input, ILogger log)
        {
            try
            {
                if (input == null || input.Count == 0)
                {
                    return;
                }

                foreach (var doc in input)
                {
                    var documentType = doc.GetPropertyValue<string>("documentType");
                    if (documentType == null)
                    {
                        log.LogWarning($"{nameof(IntermediateDataChangeFeedListener)}. " +
                            $"DocumentType missing. Document {doc.Id} will not be processed.");
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (!_processors.TryGetValue(documentType, out var processor))
                    {
                        log.LogWarning($"{nameof(IntermediateDataChangeFeedListener)}. " +
                            $"Handler not found. Document of type {documentType} will not be processed.");
                        continue;
                    }

                    await processor.Process(doc.ToString(), log);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.LogError($"Fail to process change feed in intermediatedata container. Message: {ex.Message}");
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hello, the changes are to different documents in the same container.

Comment: @RakshithaYalamanchili ok but how are you handling the documents? are you looping through the list? have you checked the count of changed documents?

Comment: Yes, I am looping through the list. Count is always one

Comment: Could you send me a code sample that actually works, I will try to run it locally to test. Also, just to re-confirm, I am making changes to multiple items within the same container. Each item is considerably a document right?

Comment: Yes each item in a container is a document, I just added a working example into my answer

Comment: If we use multiple instances, if one instance goes down, the other one should ideally pick it up right? But this is not happening. Why so?

Comment: that is described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/change-feed-processor

Comment: I am running my code on service fabric clusters. Could this be an issue?

Comment: No it just means you need to handle more things in your code